how to create multiple html files with vite?
I'm having a hard time trying to use vite. I have 2 html files and I would like to generate them with the imports automatically. However I've been able to do only one. I'm trying to import tachyons.css for all the pages right? That I could do it. but I also wanna create specific scripts for each page I don't know how to config to set automatically. Not even compile it.
import { defineConfig, Plugin } from "vite";

import { createHtmlPlugin } from "vite-plugin-html";

export default defineConfig({
  root: "src",
  plugins: [
    createHtmlPlugin({
      minify: true,
      entry: "js/home.ts",

      pages: [
        { filename: "index", template: "index.html" },
        { filename: "about", template: "about.html" },
      ],
    }),
  ],

  build: {
    outDir: "../dist",
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
});


in home.ts I'm only importing the tachyons e the about.ts is not beeing compiled and insert ed into about.html
this is the structure of my folder


What you probably want to ask is not the multi-page solution in vite, but the api in vite-plugin-html.
You can try the code below to see if it works, or check the official plug-in information.
createHtmlPlugin({
      minify: true,
      pages: [
        {
          entry: 'src/js/home.ts',
          filename: 'index.html',
          template: 'src/index.html',
        },
        {
          entry: 'src/js/about.ts',
          filename: 'about.html',
          template: 'src/about.html',
        }
      ]
    })
})


I trid tais as Welles but it didnt work
